# Python: ldap AttributeError

Tags: python, pip

When I  write in cmd:

```
ldap.initialize()
```

I got the communicate :

> AttributeError: module 'ldap' has no attribute 'initialize'

I searched throught posts and I have read that it should be a problem with ***ldap*** package. I followed the tips and I uninstalled **ldap** with ***pip (varsion 18.0)*** command and then I installed it again, but nothing changed. I have **ldap version 2.5.1** and **ldap3 0.4.4**

Comment: which command did you use to install ldap? Maybe you installed the wrong package? python-ldap VS ldap

Comment: py -m pip install ldap

Comment: Please share full code

Comment: Do you have a file called `ldap.py` in your working directory?

Comment: Thank you guys for  a fast help. Now, everything is passing through. I decided to download a package from internet and then just install it from a directory and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try to uninstall `ldap` again and use pip to install `python-ldap` instead, which is the correct package I believe.

See the doc there: http://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/

You might also need to install it with apt-get: `sudo apt-get install python-ldap`

Also as @glibdud mentioned, make sure you have no `ldap.py` file in your working directory